# How do I initialize ActionDispatch::ParamsParser in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mime-types

My application defines a custom Mime type for its Rest interface. So I register it in the `mime_types.rb` initializer:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.example.app-v1+xml", :xml_v1
```

and Rails correctly handles the `respond_to` blocks in the controllers.

However, I still need to tell Rails that incoming requests should be parsed as an XML, using ActionDispatch::ParamsParser. I just don't know how to use it inside an initializer. What's the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works well:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.example.app-v1+xml", :xml_v1

MyRailsApp::Application.config.middleware.delete "ActionDispatch::ParamsParser"
MyRailsApp::Application.config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, { Mime::XML_V1 => :xml_simple }
```