# How to disable XML parsing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to disable the automatic XML parsing of HTTP parameters. But I've found commands for Rails 2.x only, none of them works for 3.0:

```
config.action_controller.param_parsers.delete Mime::XML (application.rb)
ActionController::Base.param_parsers.delete Mime::XML
```

What is the equivalent in Rails 3.0?

Comment: Look at my answer to this question regarding the disabling of JSON parsing. Similar, but not identical.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212434/prevent-ruby-on-rails-3-from-parsing-json-post/10434741#10434741

Answer (score 14):

According to the latest security bulletin for [CVE-2013-0156](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ/discussion)
you can use this for Rails 3.0. 3.1 and 3.2

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS.delete(Mime::XML)
```

Comment: You're probably going to get a lot of votes in the next few days :)